# How can I test if a sound is playing in SoundManager2?

Tags: javascript, audio, soundmanager2

I'm looking for a simple way to check if SoundManager2 is currently playing a sound. I was hoping for a function like "SoundManager.isSoundPlaying" but I don't see this functionality.

Comment: No, but there is `whilePlaying()` that could be useful.

Answer (score 3):

In SoundManager 2 there's a dynamic propierty called "playState" wich returns these values:

*Numeric value indicating the current playing state of the sound.*

- 0 = stopped/uninitialised
- 1 = playing or buffering sound (play has been called, waiting for data etc.)

*Note that a 1 may not always guarantee that sound is being heard, given buffering and autoPlay status.*

So you can do something like:

```
var myAudio = soundManager.createSound({
    id: 'myAudioId',
    url: "/audiofile/url.mp3",
    autoPlay: true
});
if (myAudio.playState === 1) {
    // audio playing (or buffering)
}
```

More info in the [documentation page of SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem of "playState" is that it returns 1 even if the sound is under "pause" status.
A solution could be to check if the duration is not null, because once the sound is loaded the duration has always a value, then also check if the sound has been paused, because the duration value is kept even after you pause the sound.
A solution can be:

```
// assuming s is the soundmanager object

// playing status
if (s.duration&&!s.paused) {    

}
else {

}
```

Comment: Good followup to Snsxn's solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think soundmanager has such a variable..

I suggest using a global variable "isPlaying" default it to false, and adding "isPlaying = !isPlaying" in your play/pause click event.

Answer (score 0):

It actually has a way of saying if it's paused. Which is essentially the same thing. 
Just do

```
if(!_audioInstance.paused){
    // is playing
}
```